# Регулярное выражение на извлечение содержимого тэга

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

`$text` содержит какой-нибудь текст с множеством тегов. Как найти в $text все строки вида:

```
<тег class="black" тут его остальные свойства>тут содержимое тега</тег>
```

и заменить на содержимое тега с переводом строки, и записывать в другую переменную? Например:

> `<div class="black" id="left">левый блок</div>`

чтоб менялось на:

> `левый блок`

В общем, теги, содержимое тегов, свойства, кроме class, могут быть разными.

Comment: ХТМЛ-парсер вам надо пользовать.

Строку

    <div class="black"><b>text<i>text</i></b><div>text</div></div>

 вы не разберете регуляркой.

Comment: мне не нужен парсер, я нормально описал задачу и причём тут <div class="black"><b>text<i>text</i></b><div>text</div></div>...... у меня генерируется чёткий код, под который я и описал задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В переменной `$string` ваш текст.

Тогда строчка

```
preg_replace('/<([^\s]+)[\s+]class="black"[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/\\1>/','\\2',$string);
```

Возвратит содержимое любого тега, содержащегося в `$string` с параметром `class="black"` указанным сразу после открывающего тэга.

т.е.

`<a htrf="http://hashcode.ru" class="black">hashcode</a>` не обработается

`<a class="black" href="http://hashcode.ru">hashcode</a>` вернет hashcode

Upd: пример:

следующий HTML код

```
<h1 class="black">Пример</h1>
<div class="black" style="color:red">
    <span style="font-style:italic">
        Форум
    </span>
</div>
<a class="black" href="hashcode.ru">
    hashcode
</a>
```

Обработанный регуляркой, вернет

```
Пример
<div class="black" style="color:red">
    <span style="font-style:italic">
        Форум
    </span>
</div>
hashcode
```

т.е. тэги с `class="black"` содержащие в себе другие тэги не обрабатываются

Comment: а в $string заменятся все теги подходящие под регулярку?

Comment: да, заменяются все вхождения

Comment: Если будет 2 вложенных тега, будет веселье. Див в диве, например.

Comment: Вложенные дивы регулярка пропустит, так как она считывает содержимое *до* открывающей скобки только тогда, когда эта скобка является началом закрывающего тэга для тэга с `class="black"`